# Custom Validators Symfony2 ordering

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have an Entity with a few custom validators as in:

```
use Digital\ApplicationBundle\Validator\Constraints\ConstrainsUsername;
use Digital\ApplicationBundle\Validator\Constraints\ConstrainsProduct;
use Digital\ApplicationBundle\Validator\Constraints\ConstrainsGiftValid;

/**
 * @DigitalAssert\ConstrainsGiftValid
 */
class Gift
{

/**
 * @DigitalAssert\ConstrainsUsername
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @DigitalAssert\ConstrainsProduct
 */
private $productName;
[...]
```

My question is how i can set an order of checking....

I would like to validate my properties first and if properties are valid then I would like to check if those 2 properties are allowed to 'be' together...

So my case requires specific order of the validator.

How this could be accomplished please?

Current issue is my class validation 'ConstrainsGiftValid' kicks in before them ;S

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, handing everything in one constraint worked.

This includes binding error to specific property and erroring different messages for different failures:

```
public function isValid($gift, Constraint $constraint)
{

    // Validate product.
    /** @var $product Product */
    $product = $this->em->getRepository('DigitalApplicationBundle:Shop\Product')->findOneBy(array('name' => $gift->getProductName()));
    if (!$product instanceof Product) {

        $this->context->addViolationAtSubPath('username', $constraint->messageProduct, array('%string%' => $gift->getProductName()), null);
        return false;

    }

    // Validate user.
    /** @var $user User */
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('DigitalUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('username' => $gift->getUsername()));
    if (!$user instanceof User) {

        $this->context->addViolationAtSubPath('username', $constraint->messageUser, array('%string%' => $gift->getUsername()), null);
        return false;
    }


    // Gift correct type of the item!
    if (($product->getType() != 0) && ($user->getGender() !== $product->getType())) {

        $this->context->addViolationAtSubPath('username', $constraint->messageType, array('%string%' => $gift->getProductName()), null);
        return false;

    }

    // If already owning this product.
    foreach ($user->getWardrobe()->getProducts() as $wardrobeProduct) {
        if ($product == $wardrobeProduct) {

            $this->context->addViolationAtSubPath('username', $constraint->message, array('%string%' => $gift->getProductName(), '%user%' => $gift->getUsername()), null);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if `$username` and `$productName` go together, you would have to create a [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

**If you require a specific order of the validator, and would like to reuse the validation of these 2 fields later in your code, I think this should do it:**

<kbd>1</kbd> Create a form type for {username and productName}.

<kbd>2</kbd> Apply your validation rules on that formType. You'll need to apply the constraints on the entire form in this particular case if you want to play with the order of validation. You can therefore only throw the errors if you want to and in the order you want.

<kbd>3</kbd>You can finally embed that `formType` within your `GiftFormType`. Don't forget to use Valid constraint or set `cascade_validation` option to `true` to validate the embedded form.

Comment: hi Patt I have my 3 custom validation constraints for this... the thing is I need to order them somehow... which takes priority..

Comment: If you have 3 custom validation constraints, the validator will validate all the constraints so the order does not matter.

Comment: Hmm... so what you saying is to handle everything in my class constraint rather then to have them split?? This actually makes sense... I could validate this that way... but errors would not show up next to each property if this is just 1 property failing...

Comment: I have never tried it yet but it seems like you can add the violation to one particular field with `addViolationAtPath()` or `addViolationAt` instead of the classic `addViolation()` used in the validator. See [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContext.php#L120-L137). If you try this, can you let me know if that works? Good luck.

Comment: If you want to reuse the validation somewhere, you can create a form type for {username and productName}. And then apply your validation rules on that formType. You can finally embed that formType within your GiftFormType. Don't forget to use Valid constraint or set `cascade_validation` option to `true` to validate the embedded form.

Comment: Thanks a LOT @Patt, you have pointed me in the right direction indeed!!! Pasted my final solution...